# como usar el properties desde una clase java

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, properties

Como puedo usar dentro de una clase java lo que tengo dentro de messages.properties, referenciando cada valor del archivo properties en un campo de

messages.properties

```
 datos.solicitante.validacion.mensaje.busqueda.dni=Validando Dni...
 datos.solicitante.validacion.mensaje.busqueda.ruc=Validando Ruc...
 reniec.excepcion.dniRequerido=Debe indicar un valor de DNI
 reniec.excepcion.ciudadanoNoEncontrado=No se encontraron datos del ciudadano en RENIEC
```

Controller

```
`if(dni == null || dni.trim().equals("")){

    throw new BusinessException("reniec.excepcion.dniRequerido");}`
```

Quisiera usar por ejemplo el reniec.excepcion.dniRequerido dentro del bussinesExcepcion y tambien en otro lado del codigo

```
 else{
throw new BusinessException("reniec.excepcion.ciudadanoNoEncontrado");                          }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
imagen del archivo properties

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

En Spring boot solamente necesitas que tu archivo properties se encuentre dentro de la carpeta de recursos `src/main/resources/` para que se auto detecte.

Por ejemplo si tu archivo contiene

```
reniec.excepcion.dniRequerido=El valor para el DNI es requerido, favor de agregarlo
```

inyectarias ese valor a nivel de clase mediante

```
@Value("${reniec.excepcion.dniRequerido}")
private String mensajeExcepcionDNI;
```

para posteriormente solo referenciar la variable normalmente.

```
throw new BusinessException(mensajeExcepcionDNI);
```

### Actualizacion

Si deseas teer un mapa con solo algunos de los valores en tu clase puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera. Primero nota la jerarquia eso te ayudara a filtrar los que necesitas.

```
reniec.excepcion.dniRequerido=Debe indicar un valor de DNI
reniec.excepcion.ciudadanoNoEncontrado=No se encontraron datos del ciudadano en RENIEC
```

deberas crear una clase que refleje la estructura de tu properties

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "reniec") 
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class MisMensajesDeError {
  private Map<String, String> excepcion;
}
```

Comment: Me parece una excelente forma pero de esa forma tendria que hacer para cada mensaje ?, en mi archivo properties tengo una lista de mas de 40 mensajes. no habria una manera en la que pueda guardar en una sola variable todos los mensajes y luego al referenciarlos ahi indicar cual valor debe usar ?

Comment: Para referenciarlos de todas maneras tendrias que escribir sus nombres, pero si, efectivamente es posible, actualiza tu pregunta y con gusto lo arego. Adicionalment te invito a realizar el tour https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que sepas la funcion de los botones de la izquierda.

Comment: @LiAbelCarlosLopinta No. No usas una variable con todos los textos cargados, porque igual tienes eventualmente que elegir CUÁL usar. Tienes que dar el identificador, eventualmente. En Spring Boot funciona como lo indica Ruslan; en general para Java tienes la opción de usar Bundles. Revisa :)